# How to pass data from model to router in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to Node.js and am trying to pass some data from my DB model back to the router but I'm unable to find a solution. I have the following route file that makes a call to model:

**Route file:**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('../db');
var customers = require('../models/customers');

db.connect(function(err) {

if (err) {
  console.log('Unable to connect to MySQL.')
  process.exit(1)
  }
});

router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    customers.checkPassword(req.body.cust_id, req.body.password);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

**Model file:**

```
var db = require('../db.js');

module.exports.checkPassword = function(cust_id, password) {
    var sql = "SELECT Password FROM Shop.customers WHERE ID =" + cust_id;

    db.get().query(sql, function (err, res, fields) {

        result = res[0].Password;

        if (err) throw err
    });
};
```

My question is: how could I pass the queried result `Password` back to my `Route` file so that I can do this:

```
console.log('Password is', result);
```

I appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a promise

**Model file**

```
module.exports.checkPassword = function(cust_id, password) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const sql = "SELECT Password FROM Shop.customers WHERE ID =" + cust_id;
    db.get().query(sql, function (err, res, fields) {
        if (err) return reject(err)
        result = res[0].Password;
        return resolve(result);
    });
  });  
};
```

**Route file**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('../db');
var customers = require('../models/customers');

db.connect(function(err) {

if (err) {
  console.log('Unable to connect to MySQL.')
  process.exit(1)
  }
});

router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    customers.checkPassword(req.body.cust_id, req.body.password)
        .then((result) => {
            // DO: something with result
            res.status(200).send();
        })
        .catch(console.log); // TODO: Handle errors
});
```

With **async/await**

```
router.post('/', async function(req, res) {
    try {
      const result = await customers.checkPassword(req.body.cust_id, req.body.password)
      // DO: something with the result
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e); // TODO: handle errors
    } finally {
      res.status(200).send();
    }
});
```

I assume `console.log('Password is', result);` is just for test prupose, obviously you should never log a password! Also I suggest to move the callbabck of the routes do a different module, to improve code redability.

You might also find useful [promise-module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql) module on npm, basically a promise wrapper around mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You can delegate the credential control to another function in your DB file where you can decide on what kind of data you want to return on success and failure to find such data. Then you can access it from where you are calling it.